# Migrating from Heroku to Azure - getting the database migration right

Tags: django, postgresql, azure, heroku, database-migration

I have a Django app live on Heroku. I'm migrating it to Azure, taking advantage of the $120K/yr credit they recently offered me. Here's what I've done so far:

i) I created an Azure VM with Ubuntu (Standard_D1).

ii) I installed postgresql on it (my db of choice)

iii) I pulled my Heroku app's files from my github onto the Azure VM.

iv) I created a postgres DB on the Azure VM, and then ran `syncdb` to create the required tables.

v) I tweaked `postgresql.conf` and `pg_hba.conf` to cater to some tuning requirements and such.

vi) I took a backup from my Heroku app's dashboard, and downloaded it. This backup file's name is a random uuid, without a file format (e.g. f0af6457-1a24-47d0-881c-434f9bef7c92).

vii) I'm now gearing up to use `pg_restore` to fit the backup in the newly created+synced app on Azure VM.

Does all this sound about right so far? I have 3 questions:

---

1) *Will `pg_restore` work with the backup I got off Heroku? This backup doesn't have a file format at all; whereas I'm under the impression it has to be a `.tar` archive to be compatible with `pg_restore`.*

2) *My database is called `mydbname`. The data backup is saved at `/datadrive/backup/filename`. Thus, in my case is the correct `pg_restore` command something like: `pg_restore -d mydbname /datadrive/backup/filename`?*

3) *Once I successfully load the correct data in my Azure app, the final step, in my opinion, is to route traffic going to the Heroku app instead to the Azure app. For that, I'll tweak DNS entries. Am I missing anything else here, in your opinion?*

Comment: Hassan  the steps seem just right, for pg_restore 
pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U myuser -d mydb <filename>     Am sure that you created the backup using pg_dump

Comment: Hey Brij, thanks for chiming in. I actually didn't use `pg_dump` per se - Heroku's dashboard has an option whereby you can download a backup via pressing a button. I guess that's merely encapsulating the `pg_dump` command. So having a backup file with no file format or extension is not a problem as far as `pg_restore` is concerned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially the extension shouldn't matter, your restore should work but frankly haven't tested myself with a heroku backup.
However what I would suggest is lets make it a valid .dump file

> curl -o latest.dump `heroku pg:backups public-url --app <yourappname>`

this should be your valid .dump file, though its not any different from the backup you already have..