# Steps needed to move postgres DB from Heroku to an Azure hosted Linux-based VM (Django app)

Tags: linux, django, postgresql, azure, heroku

I have a postgres database with 40 tables residing on Heroku right now. It's a Django app, and overall rows are roughly 5 million.

I want to migrate all that to an exact replica in an **Azure VM** (which already has postgres correctly installed and set up).

**What's the safest, cleanest way to make this migration?**

Here are the steps in my head:

1) Prepare the Azure VM, by:

- switching to user `postgres` and going to psql client via typing `psql`
- creating a database called `mydatabase` via the command `CREATE DATABASE mydatabase;`
- *no need* to run `syncdb` to create tables at this stage.

2) Log onto the Heroku commandline, and run the command `heroku maintenance:on`

3) Next, run the command `heroku run pg_dump -C dbname | bzip2 | ssh  myusername@hostname "bunzip2 | psql mydatabase"` (source: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237725/copying-postgresql-database-to-another-server))

That's it. No syncdb to create table structures or anything at any point.

Can anyone comment on those steps, and rectify wherever needed? Thanks!

*Note: ask for more information in case you need it*

Comment: you should 'practice' the migration on your PC using eg Docker or Vagrant, to determine exactly the steps that are necessary to get your Azure instance in a ready state...   there are bound to be some unexpected steps!

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33912608/migrating-from-heroku-to-azure-getting-the-database-migration-right/33913512#33913512

Comment: @BrijRajSingh-MSFT: Yea we talked on that question I remember. But isn't your answer there `curl -o latest.dump heroku pg:backups public-url --app <yourappname>` just a way to take a DB backup?

Comment: That's correct, while the OP had most of the steps figured out quite correctly.

Comment: Well myself being OP of that quesion, I tried pg_restore after that in this way: `pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h example.cloudapp.net -U postgres -d mydb /home/mhb11/e38862b4-32bd-41b8-9b1c-fcaa9734b1f8?dl=0` But I got a ton of errors and it didn't work. The DB is still sitting unmigrated. What do you think about the steps I've outlined in THIS question? See any anomalies?

Comment: For instance, I get 100s of errors like: `pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "user_sessions_session_expire_date" already exists
    Command was: CREATE INDEX user_sessions_session_expire_date ON user_sessions_session USING btree (expire_date);` or `pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 2355; 2606 16916 FK CONSTRAINT user_id_refs_id_4d uv4
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  constraint "user_id_refs_id_43c39" for relation "auth_user_user_permissions" already exists
    Command was: ALTER TABLE ONLY ath_user_user_permissions`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`heroku pg:backups capture` (to capture the pg backup)

`curl -o latest.dump heroku pg:backups public-url` (to download the pg backup to your local machine)

`ls -lh latest.dump` (to check the size of the downloaded file, so you're certain you downloaded the complete file)

`scp -P <your port e.g. 2222> latest.dump user@example.cloudapp.net:/home/user` (this will transfer the file to your remote machine)

Then on your remote machine:
`pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -U myuser -d mydb latest.dump`

Hopefully this gets the job done.